# How do I activate language localisation on my wordpress.org plugin?

Tags: wordpress, localization, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have a wordpress plugin in english. I have just added .po and .mo files to the [/languages folder](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/trelis-crypto-payments/tags/1.0.16/languages/) to support Spanish. However, the localisation is [not showing](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/trelis-crypto-payments/).

I don't believe I have to load the text-domain because I'm using a recent Wordpress version.

Do I need to add something else to make this localisation active?

Comment: IIRC plugin will only automatically load these files if WordPress downloads them automatically from wordpress.org. And that's only if Spanish translations are available for your plugin on wordpress.org. If that's not the case then your plugin would have to load these files by itself.

Comment: You're not using any translation functions i.e.: `_e(), __(), etc` in your code, without those functions translation won't work.

Comment: Do I need to add __() to the headers as well? And how do I localise the ReadMe.txt